# Many to many relation with an extra column rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got two players engaging a single activity and they exchange messages during that time, since many players play on many activities with other players, I started to work on a message archiving feature, and I'm having some issues about the design, since I want to archive per activity.

In my message model every message has an `activity_id` field.

My user model :

```
has_many :sent_messages, :foreign_key => 'sender_id', :class_name => Message
has_many :received_messages, :foreign_key => 'receiver_id', :class_name => Message
```

My archived_message :

```
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => User
  belongs_to :message, :class_name => Message
  attr_accessible :activity_id
```

And I've just added tried to add this to my model :

```
has_many :activity_archived_messages, :through => :archived_messages, :source => :message
```

Now this is the part I've been struggling a bit, because I want to archive both received and sent messages if they belong to the same activity.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `Activity` to your model, and then archive that:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :messages
  has_and_belongs_to_many :participants, class_name: User
end
```

Now, you can archive *this*, and have all the related messages, in both directions, saved in your archive.